# Autorotation for iphone4 & iphone5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, autorotate

Im developing app for both iphone4 & 5. when i use shouldAutoRotation it support only for iphone4. When i use willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation it supports for only iphone5. Im using both method for iphone4 &5, it working. Im going to publish my app to appStore. I got some warnings, but will work perfectly. Is apple reject app for getting warnings.

code:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        //returns true if want to allow orientation change
        return TRUE;


    }
    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        //decide number of origination tob supported by Viewcontroller.
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;


    }

    - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
        //from here you Should try to Preferred orientation for ViewController

        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)  interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {



        if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

//My code here


    }

}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {


        if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

//My code here

    }
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Apple will probably accept your app, warning are not errors, but it depends on the kind of warning, of course... could you please post the warnings? add lines as comments belove each line of code with warning, please...

Comment: Appstore won't reject your app , but warnings in Objective-C are of importance, so try to `Treat Warnings as Errors`

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterface is deprecated in ios6;         UITextAlignmentLeft is deprecated in ios6;    this is my warnings

Answer (score 0):

you may have missed to close with "}" this method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

     if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {


        if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

             //My code here

        }

    return YES;
    }
  // add:
  return YES;
}
```

and the same for willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method...

Comment: willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation won't need return YES; Am I correct?

Comment: @Ram no you are wrong, every method with a return value must return a value for all cases, otherwise you get a warning

Comment: you must return a bool (YES or NO, just you know what the default value should be)

Comment: willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation is void. So it won't need return value.

Comment: right, sorry, i was talking about my answer (shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation), where you had a case not returning anything